# I need to add numbers to this regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I am using:

```
[^\w\s]
```

I tried this out at http://regexr.com/ and it does most of what I want it to do except I need to include numbers to this pattern as well. I found this

```
[0-9]
```

which works for numbers on their own, but I need to combine this with my existing regex.

To test the expression try http://regexr.com/ I need something that will also get all of the numbers

Comment: Add some sample input you're trying to match.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? JS?

Comment: it doesnt for some reason? @RionWilliams If you use the pattern at http://regexr.com/ it doesnt seem to work

Comment: You may use an alternation: `[^\w\s]|[0-9]` (or to match a sequence - `(?:[^\w\s]|[0-9])+`, or `((?!\s)[\W\d])+`). Edit: For JS, you can just unroll the `\w` and adjust as in Rion's answer. For other flavors, like .NET, Java, Ruby, Swift etc. there can be other means to achieve this.

Comment: You can use: `[^a-zA-Z_\s]` and it will match numbers

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm new to regex so I dont know but I'm using javascript if that helps.

Comment: @ceckenrode: Why not accept the answer below :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` metacharacter will match any alphanumeric characters and underscores `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so if you wanted to include numbers, just replace the `\w` character with `a-zA-Z_` :

```
[^a-zA-Z_\s]
```

This would match any non-alphabetic, underscore or white-space characters.